# How to create wifi hotspot in opensuse 13.2

Tags: opensuse, wifi-hotspot

Using Opensuse 13.2 on a Toshiba Satellite.

I have been unable, so far, to make WiFi hotspot in my laptop, so that I can access internet from my WiFi enabled devices. How can I make it a hot-spot?

Comment: If you use NetworkManager on your Laptop it is much easier. Follow this NetworkManager Tutorial on youtube that I just tested on Tumbleweed, while the video shows Leap 42.1. On both it works and should so on 13.2 or older as long as this feature was not added recently to NM. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auQ5tC1u6fM​

Answer (score 2):

Having a proper, guest-friendly hotspot on a Linux machine require at least the following:

1. switch your WiFi card to master (AP) mode - to make your AP secure you need to configure and run *hostapd* with at least *WPA2-PSK* auth;
2. make you host a NAT-enabled router, which you can achieve with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s INPUT_CIDR -o OUTPUT_INTERFACE -j SNAT --to YOUR_PUBLIC_IP` and `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`;
3. a DNS forwarder and (more importantly) DHCP server - *dnsmasq* can do both.

I have a set of Bash scripts to configure Linux as a WiFi hotspot in just 2 commands. I can share it if necessary.

Comment: Now I have installed hostapd and downloaded hotspotd.Then configured it through "sudo hotspotd start" but no network is detected in my android phone.

Comment: I can help with manual configuration, but have no idea about `hotspotd`, sorry.

Comment: Can you provide `iwconfig wlan0` output, run as root when the *hostapd* and *hotspotd* are running? Replace *wlan0* with your wireless interface name.

Comment: It says "wlan0 no such device" :\

Comment: Replace *wlan0* with your WiFi interface name.

Comment: I found 3 network interfaces like this network interface:
  enp1s0               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  wlp5s0               Ethernet network interface
Now I gave respective commands with "iw config" and it gives same o/p s